# "ValueError: Unpack failed: incomplete input"

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, msgpack

```py
with open('discord-gitlab.msgpack', 'rb') as database:
    try:
        print("Получены данные из файла БД:" + str(msgpack.unpackb(database.read())))
        discord_gitlab = msgpack.unpackb(database.read())
    finally:
        discord_gitlab = dict()
        print(msgpack.unpackb(database.read()))
```

Said about some "incomplete input" while there's no such mode in `open()`.

Tried using `close()`, with and without `with … as …:`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print("Получены данные из файла БД:" + str(msgpack.unpackb(database.read())))
discord_gitlab = msgpack.unpackb(database.read())
```

The first line calls `database.read()`, which reads all of the data.

Then the second line calls `database.read()` again, but there's nothing left to read, so `read()` returns an empty string.

So `msgpack.unpackb()` receives an empty string, which presumably is the cause of the error.

You can fix this by calling `.read()` only once and saving the results in a variable, like this:

```
data = database.read()
print("Получены данные из файла БД:" + str(msgpack.unpackb(data)))
discord_gitlab = msgpack.unpackb(data)
```